# Describing the universal property of the evaluation map

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification, universal-property, representable-functor

*[Emily Riehl's "Category Theory in Context"](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf)*,  ${\rm Exercise}~2.3.{\rm iii}.$

> The set $B^A$ of functions from a set $A$ to a set $B$ represents the contravariant functor ${\rm Set}(-\times A,B):{\rm Set}^{\rm op}\to{\rm Set}$. The universal element for this representation is a function
>   $${\rm ev}:B^A\times A\to B$$
>   called the **evaluation map**. Define the evaluation map and descripe its universal property, in analogy with the universal bilinear map $\otimes$ of Example $2.3.7$ (*the tensor product*).

I will start by descrping the universal property. For a representable functor, a universal element $x\in Fc$ defines a natural isomorphism $\mathcal C(-,c)\cong F$ (in the contravariant case, as given). Given ${\rm ev}\in{\rm Set}(B^A\times A,B)$ is a universal element, the induced natural isomorphism arises as
$${\rm Set}(X,B^A)\cong{\rm Set}(X\times A,B)$$
In particular, for every map $\bar f:B^A\to X$ there bijectively corresponds a map $f:X\times A\to B$ identified with each other via the natural isomorphism. Consider the following commutative square induced by $\bar f:B^A\to X$
$$\tag D\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
{\rm Set}(B^A,B^A) @>{\cong}>>{\rm Set}(B^A\times A,B)\\
@V{\bar f^*}VV @VV{\bar f^*\times{\rm id}_A}V\\
{\rm Set}(X,B^A) @>{\cong}>>{\rm Set}(X\times A,B)
\end{CD}$$
Tracing $1_{B^A}$ around reveals $f={\rm ev}\circ(\bar f\times{\rm id}_A)$ which is  in fact the universal property of the evaluation map. The map itself can be defined as
$${\rm ev}:B^A\times A\to B,~(g,a)\mapsto g(a)$$

> Is this account sufficient or have I left out something crucial? Following up, is the diagram $($D$)$ correct as it stands, i.e. are all arrows pointing in the correct direction (which boils down to: are $f$ and $\bar f$ correctly defined)?

Thanks in advance!

---

*Remark*: the notation $f^*$ refers to pre-composition with $f$.

Comment: You have the direction of $\bar{f}$ reversed; remember that the blank in $\mathrm{Set}(-\times A,B)$ is *contravariant*.

Comment: (Which is to say, the direction of $\bar{f}^*$ in the diagram is correct, but $\bar{f}:B^A\to X$ is not.)

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Ah, I thought that I messed that up somewhere; thank you for pointing out!

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Beside reversed direction; is there anything else which I missed or which could be improved?

Comment: It looks good to me, besides that. Maybe it would be good to add some detail on why the map you define has the appropriate universal property (which it does), but that's more for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Thank you for your help! If you'd like you could write a short answer to close up this thread; otherwise I'll just do it myself (also, for the sake of completeness `^^`).

Comment: Would the downvoter please elaborate on his issue with this question?